# 'value' is attached to all hooks

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

No matter what hook I use, if I press Save, the 'value' will automatically. I am very stressed out because of this.
I will be greatly moved if you help me.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erk17.png)

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { value useEffect, value useState } from 'react';

function TestPage() {
  console.log(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_WECODE_URI);

  const [state, setState] = useState('');

  const customFetch = async () => {
    const results = await axios.get(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_WECODE_URI}/testapi`);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    customFetch();
  }, []);

  return <div>{state}</div>;
}

export default TestPage;
```

Comment: Remove the word value. It's not valid typescript

Comment: If removed, it will continue to be created again. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function TestPage() {
  console.log(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_WECODE_URI);

  const [state, setState] = useState();

  const customFetch = async () => {
    const results = await axios.get(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_WECODE_URI}/testapi`);
    setState(results)
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    customFetch();
  }, []);

  return <div>{state}</div>;
}

export default TestPage;
```

Comment: when your are using import from any package , vscode automaticly prefix `value` attach 
because config prettier may be wrong , disable prettier in extension and re enable it

Comment: Thank you so much! I think it's the question you said!